# “UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte" after convert from python 3.6.1 to 3.6.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Since migrating to python 3.6.5, database query error details are being lost and all I am seeing is the dreaded UnicodeDecodeError.

If I switch back to python 3.6.1, I can see the error details when running the same python script. Example errors are invalid field name and query timeout.

I get the same UnicodeDecodeError with python 3.7.

I am using pyodbc to make database connections to transfer data from SQL Server to SQL Server and Oracle.

I purposely changed a field name to an incorrect value in the source database query. When I run that script with python 3.6.1, I see:
pyodbc.Error: (' ', "[ ] ERROR: Field not found 'MyBadFieldName' in view with...

With python 3.6.5, I do not see the pyodbc error at all. Instead I see:
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 2: invalid start byte" error.

My thought is that the invalid start byte is contained in the string returned by pyodbc.Error

Thus I though that I should be decoding to avoid the UnicodeDecodeError.

I tried decoding some strings in my code but kept getting syntax errors. So tried decoding the database connection.

My SQL Server collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I saw some articles suggesting the following with that collation:
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='latin1', to=str)
cnxn.setencoding(str, encoding='latin1')

When I include that in my python script and run with python 3.6.5 I get the following error on the setdecoding line:
NameError: name 'pyodbc' is not defined
I am guessing that I am missing some library to avoid that error.

Can anyone suggest how I can solve this problem?

Thanks!

Vern